# How to Picture in Picture on mac in any app?

Tags: macos, picture-in-picture

I want to use Picture in Picture feature that MacOS has with safari or iTunes but with any app. For example I want to know my cores work with `htop` in an iTerm instance always on display like this:

[image]

but this feature seems to be only in those apps. Is there any built-in app that can do this?

Comment: Would splitting windows work for your question?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any built-in app that can do this?

There is no built-in way in macOS that can do this. Picture in Picture is available only for watching videos:

- [Watch video using Picture in Picture on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT206997)

Comment: this is really sad